# How can I destroy bullets using RayCast2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

The projectiles of my game are too fast; some of bullets are passing through the collider.

I did a `RayCast` ray to detect the colliders and it's working. I'm having trouble trying to do a `RayCast2D` to destroy the bullet when it hits the collider.

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && Time.time > nextfire)
{
    nextfire = Time.time + firerate;
    anim.SetTrigger("Shoot");
    GameObject tempBullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, shotSpawner.position, 
        shotSpawner.rotation);
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(shotSpawner.position, shotSpawner.right);
    Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.right * 300f, Color.cyan);

    if (hit.collider.tag != null)
    {
        nextfire = Time.time;
        print(hit.collider.name);
    }
    else
    {
        print(hit.collider.name);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Somewhat off-topic: Have you looked into [Object Pooling](https://www.raywenderlich.com/847-object-pooling-in-unity) for bullets rather than instantiating/destroying the prefabs? It helps with performance and with your specific question, you could just deactivate the bullets on collision.

Comment: Where is the collision detection code?

Comment: No, Im starting with unity and c# , thanks for the Object Pooling  advice!

Comment: Use continuous collision detection mode?

Comment: Yes, but the bullets are small and fast, the continuous collison cant detect all of them